# Stable diffusion - Can you craft a prompt to remove something in a masked area

Tags: prompt-design, stable-diffusion

Within Stable Diffusion, is it possible to mask a particular area on an image, and craft a prompt to instruct the system to remove an element from it.

For example, to take a picture of a man holding something, and to mask their hand out and ask the AI to redraw the hand minus the object?

This is as opposed to simply masking the hand and crafting a prompt to draw another hand, or using a negative prompt for the specific object. One that actually instructs the AI to remove an object as part of the additive process. Regardless of how counter intuitive this may seem.

Comment: wouldn't this actually be equivalent to masking out only the areas covered by the object? Your problem doesn't seem to be tied to the inpainting, your issue is that most tools have a circular masking brush that obviously is not that great for similar tasks. I think I once saw a demo on Hugging Face that implemented masks that would allow you to click on an object and have it selected, I will try to find it again

Comment: I'm asking this from a prompt crafting perspective, masking would be a seperate question.

Comment: @SPArcheon, then you'd get an empty hand still in a holding position, not a redrawn hand in a different position holding nothing

Comment: Then I am not sure to understand what you want to achieve. Either you try to keep the same hand without the object or draw a new one. Are you instead focusing on **HOW** you tell the tool to remove the object? In that case I think you are looking for what some call "Instruction based img-to-img". There are a few examples on Hugging Face, but I didn't really had any good result with those.

Comment: @SPArcheon, as per the original question, I'm asking how to do this using a prompt, rather than the other available method, or to confirm that it can't be done.